# Auto creating Services along with Pods

Tags: kubernetes

I have a Kubernetes scenario where I will need to deploy 3 Redis servers (pods), and each needs to be exposed with a ClusterIP service. Something like;

- RedisClusterIP1 -> RedisPod1
- RedisClusterIP2 -> RedisPod2
- RedisClusterIP3 -> RedisPod3

I have deployment plan like below, but as you can see it is creating ClusterIP service manually, and binds single of them to all pods.

Is there any way to set a deployment plan, there it will create same amount of services with Pods?

I checked [deployments](https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/workloads/controllers/deployment/) and [replica sets](https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/workloads/controllers/replicaset/) but could not figure out if there is something already exists.

```
apiVersion: extensions/v1beta1
kind: Deployment
metadata:
  name: redisharedis
spec:
  replicas: 3
  template:
    metadata:
      labels:
        app: redisharedis
    spec:
      containers:
        - name: redisharedis
          image: aozdemir/redisharedis:v6
          resources:
            limits:
              cpu: "1"
              memory: "800Mi"
            requests:
              cpu: "0.1"
              memory: "200Mi"
          ports:
            - containerPort: 6379


---
apiVersion: v1
kind: Service
metadata:
  name: redisharedis-service
  labels:
    name: redisharedis-service
spec:
  ports:
    - port: 6379
      targetPort: 6379
      protocol: TCP
  selector:
    app: redisharedis
  type: ClusterIP
```

Answer (score 5):

This can be done If you're deploying your redis cluster as `Statefulset` rather than `deployment`. In Kubernetes 1.9+, StatefulSet automatically adds the Pod name as a label on each of its Pods, so you can enable Service-Per-Pod like this:

```
apiVersion: apps/v1beta2
kind: StatefulSet
metadata:
  annotations:
    service-per-pod-label: "statefulset.kubernetes.io/pod-name"
    service-per-pod-ports: "80:8080"
```

You need to install `MetaController` in your kubernetes cluster to install one service per pod. Please refer following link for detailed instructions:

> https://github.com/GoogleCloudPlatform/metacontroller/tree/master/examples/service-per-pod